# Order of INSERT or UPDATE in a transaction in binlog

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I'm using debezium connector to stream my Mysql binlog change records to Kafka Topic. My transaction is like so:

Tx begin

```
Insert INTO Project(Name, InProgress) VALUES ('New Project', 0);
    -- We get the created id (say PID)
Insert INTO Tasks(TaskName, ProjectID) VALUES ('Task A', PID);
    -- We get the taskID (say TID1)
Insert INTO Tasks(TaskName, ProjectID) VALUES ('Task B', PID);
    -- We get the taskID (say TID2)
UPDATE Tasks SET TaskName = 'Task C' where ID = TID2;
Update Project SET InProgress = 1 where ID = PID;
```

Tx end

My question is in what order will I get the bin log records? Will I get the records in the order in which the records are inserted? So like this?

```
NEW Project with ID = PID
NEW Task with ID = TID1
NEW Task with ID = TID2
```

Is this documented anyplace?

Comment: They will be a transaction within the binlog, and applied as such. With this behavior is the order important?

Comment: It is important, because I want to create an Elastic Search document. So when I get Project record, I create the document with that PID,  and as and when I get Task record, I update the ES record. So if Task record is received before Project record, there would be no existing ES record to update..

Comment: @Ouroboros did you get an answer to this question? We have the exact same use case - mysql to ES and we now have a case where order within binlog transaction matters.